# How to record sound by using the browser by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, request

If you call this request (using bash), you will get a response:

```
curl 'https://translate.google.com/_/TranslateWebserverUi/data/batchexecute?rpcids=MkEWBc&f.sid=5613576154274168367&bl=boq_translate-webserver_20210525.06_p0&hl=en&soc-app=1&soc-platform=1&soc-device=1&_reqid=1641564&rt=c' \
  -H 'authority: translate.google.com' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"' \
  -H $'x-goog-batchexecute-bgr: ' \
  -H 'x-same-domain: 1' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'origin: https://translate.google.com' \
  -H 'x-client-data: ' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://translate.google.com/' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8' \
  -H 'cookie: ' \
  --data-raw 'f.req=%5B%5B%5B%22MkEWBc%22%2C%22%5B%5B%5C%22%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA%5C%22%2C%5C%22fa%5C%22%2C%5C%22en%5C%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B3%5D%5D%22%2Cnull%2C%22generic%22%5D%5D%5D&at=AD08yZm2xeWxbruXnnzNXfpl0lR9%3A1622098959780&' \
  --compressed
```

What's the scenario?  That request is made by `google.translator` (web). Also, it is a speech-to-text API. In other words, all I have done is clicking on the bottom-left mic-icon and said: "test" (by my sound). then sent it to the server and seen "test" word (as text) in the textarea.

My question is, how the following part (which is my sound, I guess) is handled by JavaScript:

```
f.req=%5B%5B%5B%22MkEWBc%22%2C%22%5B%5B%5C%22%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA%5C%22%2C%5C%22fa%5C%22%2C%5C%22en%5C%22%2Ctrue%5D%2C%5B3%5D%5D%22%2Cnull%2C%22generic%22%5D%5D%5D&at=AD08yZm2xeWxbruXnnzNXfpl0lR9%3A1622098959780&
```

What's this? Is it a sound converted to text? How it is produced?

Comment: it could be being done by chrome instead of JS, but you can do that in JS. look into record.js for example.

Comment: To record sound through JS, you can use already existing libraries or use [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia).

Answer (score 0):

Google Translate most likely uses [Web Speech API](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/) to convert speech to text. This JS API allows you to produce a result without re-inventing the wheel, as you can see in a [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API) provided by Google.

The request you've spotted is encoded. After decoding using urldecode function it looks like this:

```
f.req=[[["MkEWBc","[[\"تست\",\"fa\",\"en\",true],[3]]",null,"generic"]]]&at=AD08yZm2xeWxbruXnnzNXfpl0lR9:1622098959780&
```

As you can see it consists of some identifiers along with your input (`تست` –> `test`).